# Looking for an Extension of an extensive link list

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

For the construction of an extensive list of links, since the source page is a thematic portal, I am looking for a suitable EXT., Which also runs under TYPO3 7.6 LTS.
it if the list of links to a permits the use of categories and multiple categorization of links is possible would be nice. should Weiterrhin the links are described not only the destination address and an alias but here should still an outline of the target page (possibly with photo) be possible.
Additional functions such as proposing links by users, reporting broken links or even a User Voting would nice additional features.

There were times the Modern Linklist, but they were no longer being developed for TYPO3 <6.x.

Is there perhaps somewhere an alternative or as one might like to vorhnandenen solutions might realize? It would be nice of course, without any programming knowledge, since I'm not a programmer.

P.S .: It is not about building a spam list but high quality links with topics relating to the original page.

Comment: I don't know any extension for that use case. What about letting someone code it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this seems to be a straight forward usage you could try to build that extension by yourself with the ExtensionBuilder.

just build up the records neccessary for your data. and let the EB generate all usefull actions: `list` & `show`, even `create`, `edit`, `delete` in FE would be possible.

Afterwards you just need to edit the generated fluid templates.

these links may help:

1. [Overview](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Extbase/FirstExtbaseExtension.html)
2. [EB manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/Index.html)

*small remark*: if you want the newest code state, use the EB from git instead of TER

Comment: Is it really so easy , even if you , like me, have no programming skills ?

Comment: you should try it. it's as easy as to define all your fields in a record. (view the links I added)

Answer (score 2):

I`m not aware of an existing extension for it but it could be a good project to learn extbase / fluid.

You should also take a look at

```
typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu
```

and

```
typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Classes/ViewHelpers/Menu
```

Fluid Content contains everything you need to create a list like that, you "just" have to combine the necessary bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot with TYPO3 core functionality: there is a page type "external URL", pages can have categories by default, there are plenty of menu options (TypoScript HMENU, menu content elements, Fluid menu Viewhelpers). The Linkvalidator can periodically check all links and report broken links.
For suggestions you could add a form. Powermail for example can also store submitted info in database records, so your visitors could prepare page records (they are hidden until you make them visible).